# How to register dependent services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control

I register the HttpClient like:

```
services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();
```

then further down in the code I want to register another interface that depends on this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyRepository>(
    new MyRepository("<string>",
        "<string>",
        "<string>",
        ???,
        logger));
```

So I am not sure what to put in ???. I could put 'new HttpClient()' but that kind of defeats the purpose of registering HttpClient. I basically need the method that I call to get the reference that has already been added. Ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: `var httpClient = new HttpClient(); services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(httpClient);services.AddSingleton<IMyRepository>(new MyRepository("<string>", "<string>", "<string>", httpClient, logger));` ?

Answer (score 4):

Resolve it from the service provider:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyRepository>(serviceProvider =>
    new MyRepository("<string>",
        "<string>",
        "<string>",
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>(),
        logger));
```

By the way, you probably want to use HttpClientFactory (`services.AddHttpClient();`) instead of `services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();`.

See [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) for information on the DNS issues that occur with a long-lived static (or singleton) HttpClient and why you should use HttpClientFactory.

Comment: I get an error message that - 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddHttpClient' . . . .

Comment: @KevinBurton Ah, you might have to install the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` NuGet package for HttpClientFactory to be available.